# How do I allow changing of Active Directory passwords via unsecured LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, windows-registry

As you might already know AD does not let you change the password through LDAP if you don't have a secure connection to AD. I heard that there is a registry setting to change this behavior but so far couldn't find where it is... Anyone of you know how can I can change this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to disable this by changing the local security policy on  the domain controller(s) for 'digitally signed server communications'

This can be found in

```
Computer->WindowsSettings->LocalPolicies->SecurityOptions
```

Obviously you  need to be aware of the security hole you would be opening on your DC when doing this.